# Show $11^{11}+12^{12}+13^{13} =10k$ without direct calculation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, divisibility

Prove that $11^{11}+12^{12}+13^{13}$ is divisible by $10$.
Obviously you could just put that in to a calculator and see the results, but I was wondering about some of the other approaches to this? I have not studied modulus', so if you could explain it without them, it would be better for me. Thanks!

Comment: Do calculators now have enough precision to compute $13^{13}$ exactly?

Comment: What about taking mod $10$ ??

Comment: Working modulo $10$ is simply the same as only looking at the final digit. There are all sorts of ways of approaching this. The most efficient ones will use the tricks of modular arithmetic, which were designed for just such problems and encode the patterns which you will notice if you do more of the calculations by hand. I am sure you will get some elementary answers, but it is worth noting some of the other things people say as well, and either look them up, or look out for them as you learn, because you will find they come in handy to know.

Comment: If $n$ has a last digit of $a$ and $m$ has a last digit of $b$ then $n =10k +a$ and $m=10j + b$. Note: $n^z=(10k + a)^z$ and all we are interested in is the last digit then it has the same last digit as $a^z$.  And $n + m = 10k + 10j + a + b$ so we only have to consider *those* last digits.  So this become a math based on "last digits" and that's *much* easier.

Comment: FYI:  Modulus arithmetic simply means doing arithmetic on remainders.  The important thing is that to find the remainder of an expression with large values, it is good enough to do the expression on just the remainders.  So the remaider of $32^9*43+52$ when divided by $7$ it's enough to take the remainder of $32:(4)$, the remainder of $43:(1)$ and the remainder of $52:(3)$ an find out the remainder of $4^9*1+3$.  And to figure and $4^9$ we figure $4^2=16$ has remainder $2$.  So $4^3$ has remainder $2*4=8$ which has remainder $1$.  And $4^3$ has remainder $1*4=4$ and so on.

Comment: I sympathize with "I don't know modulo arithmetic" but I also think if one has "$a \equiv b\pmod n$ means $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $n$" then nearly every one of these answers that use modulo arithmetic *WILL* be easy to follow and make very clear sense.

Answer (score 2):

$13^4$ ends with $1$ so does $13^{12}$ and thus $13^{13}$ ends with $3$

$12^4$ ends with $6$ so $12^{12}$ also ends with $6$

$11^{11}$ ends with $1$ so your statement is valid.

Comment: How do you know $13^4$ ends with $1$?  I'd add words to the effect  you can find the last digit by only considering the last digit (because everything else is a multiple of 10).

Comment: $13^2$ ends with 9 so $13^4$ ends with...

Comment: Right, but I think we should spell it out gently.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $a^4\equiv1$ mod $5$ if $5\not\mid a$, we find

$$11^{11}+12^{12}+13^{13}\equiv
\begin{cases}1+0+1\equiv0\mod 2\\
1+1+3\equiv0\mod 5
\end{cases}$$

**Added later**: Here is an alternative way to show that $11^{11}+12^{12}+13^{13}$ is a multiple of $10$ without resorting to modular arguments. All that's needed is the algebraic identity $x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\cdots+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$ with various interpretations of $x$, $y$, and $n$ (e.g., $x=12^4$, $y=6^4$ and $n=3$).

Note that $1+6+13=20$ is a multiple of $10$. It follows that $11^{11}+12^{12}+13^{13}$ is a multiple of $10$ if and only if $(11^{11}-1)+(12^{12}-6^{12})+(6^{12}-6)+(13^{13}-13)$ is a multiple of $10$.  But

$$\begin{align}
11^{11}-1&=(11-1)(11^{10}+11^9+\cdots+11+1)\\
&=10(11^{10}+11^9+\cdots+11+1)\\
12^{12}-6^{12}&=(12^4-6^4)(12^8+12^46^4+6^8)\\
&=(12^2+6^2)(12^2-6^2)(12^8+12^46^4+6^8)\\
&=(144+36)(12^2-6^2)(12^8+12^46^4+6^8)\\
&=180(12^2-6^2)(12^8+12^46^4+6^8)\\
6^{12}-6&=6(6^{11}-1)\\
&=6(6-1)(6^{10}+6^9+\cdots+1)\\
&=30(6^{10}+6^9+\cdots+1)\\
13^{13}-13&=13(13^{12}-1)\\
&=13(13^4-1)(13^8+13^4+1)\\
&=13(13^2+1)(13^2-1)(13^8+13^4+1)\\
&=13(169+1)(13^2-1)(13^8+13^4+1)\\
&=13\cdot170(13^2-1)(13^8+13^4+1)\\
\end{align}$$

Remark: This approach is, of course, more convoluted than the modular approach. (It also relies in part on knowing which terms, such as $12^2+6^2$, will produce a factor of $10$.)  If anything, it should demonstrate the value of learning how modular arithmetic works!

Comment: That's surely beyond the OPs exposure to number theory, don't you think?

Comment: @fleablood, the OP only just now added the disclaimer about not having studied modular arithmetic. Before that it was hard to tell what they did or didn't know.

Comment: what does OP refer to, stands for??

Comment: @MagedSaeed, Original Post(er).

Comment: @fleablood The 2nd approach above uses only the Factor Theorem so it is  likely accessible to the OP. Slightly more streamlined is to use the Binomial Theorem as I do in my answer, but that's still far from the elegance and simplicity of modular arithmetic .

Comment: But anyone familiar with modular arithmetic would not have asked this question in the first place.

Comment: @fleablood I agree (and the OP says they have not studied modular arithmetic). But the 2nd approach in Barry's answer does not use modular arithmetic. Looking closer I see that was added in an edit after your original comment (and the OP's edit).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to show that the units digit is zero pretty easily.

Comment: This is the shortest and most to the point answer!

Comment: If MPW provides an example or some steps to show that the units digit is zero, then it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, the trick is to realize that the last digit of $n^k$ is the same as the last digit of the last digit of $n$ to the $k$.  So the last digit of $11^{11}$ is the same as the last digit of $1^{11} = 1$ and the last digit of $12^{12}$ is the same as the last digit of $2^{12}$ and the last digit of $13^{13}$ is the same as the last digit of $3^{13}$. Now you might think finding out the last digit of $3^{13}$ is hard but if we "throw away" every thing but the last digit is easy: $3^2=9; 3^3=9*3=27=7; 3^4=7*3=21=1;3^5=1*3=3;3^6=3*3=9;3^7=9*3=27=7...$ etc. notice that last digit of $3^4$ is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Last digit of $11^{11}$ is obviously 1.

$12^1$ ends at 2. $12^2$ ends at 4. $12^3$ at 8. $12^4$ at 6, and $12^5$ again at 2. So, last digit of $12^{12}$ is 6.

$13^1$ ends at 3. $13^2$ at 9. $13^3$ at 7, $13^4$ ends at 1 and $13^5$ again ends at 3. Hence, $13^{13}$ ends at 3.

Finally, $11^{11}+12^{12}+13^{13}$ ends at 0 at your number is divisible by 10.

Answer (score 0):

Tedious the first time you do it way but once you do it is obvious:

$$11^{11} = (10 + 1)^{11} = 10^{11} + 11*10^{10} + 55*10^9..... + 55*10^2 + 11*10 + 1 = 10M + 1$$ for $M= 10^{10} + 11*10^{9} + 55*10^8..... + 55*10 + 11$.  But ... THE EXACT VALUE OF $M$ WILL NOT MATTER!!!... The *only* thing that matters is the remander $1$.

Likewise $$12^{12} = (10 + 2)^{12} = 10^{12} + 12*2*10^{11} + 66*2^2*10^{10} + .... . + 66*2^{10}*10^2+ 12*2^{11}*10 + 2^{12} = 10N + 2^{12}$$ for $N = 10^{12} + .... \text{oh, what that hell do we care}$.

And $$13^{13} = (10+3)^{13} = 10^{13} + 13*10^{12}*3 + ..... +13*10*3^{12} + 3^{12} = 10K + 3^{13}$$ for $K = \text{whatever}$.

So $$11^{11}+12^{12}+13^{13} = 10N + 10M + 10K + 1 + 2^{12} + 3^{13}$$.  But since we are only interested in whether it is divisible by $10$ we can ignore the $10N + 10M + 10K$ because it is divisible by $10$.

So for all that tedious work we've come up with the simple and useful idea that "if we want to find out if something is divisible by $10$ we only have to do math on the remainders.  We could have done that in our heads!

If $\equiv_{10}$ means "has the same remainder when divided by $10$" we could have done that in one line:

$$11^{11} + 12^{12} + 13^{13}\equiv_{10} 1^{11} + 2^{12} + 3^{13}$$

$1^{11} = 1$ of course.

And we can do $2^{12}$ in steps.

$2^2 = 4; 2^4= 4^2 = 16=10+6\equiv_{10} 6$.

$2^8 = (10 + 6)^2 = 100 + 2*6*10 + 36= 10M + 6\equiv{10}  6$.

So $2^{12} = 2^8*2^4 = (10M + 6)(10 +6) =100M + 6*10 + 10*6M + 6*6\equiv_{10}6*6=36\equiv_{10} 6$.

At this point we should realize we can just go deirectly to working with remainders.

$3^{2} = 9; 3^4 = 9^2 = 81 \equiv_{10} 1$.  So $3^{13}3^4*3^4*3^4*3\equiv_{10} 1*1*1*3=3$.

So  if we had used this concept of remainders from the begining we'd have done it in two or three lines:

$11^{11} + 12^{12} + 13^{13} \equiv_{10}$

$1^{11} + 2^{12} + 3^{13} \equiv_{10}$

$1 + (2^4)^3 +(3^4)^3 \times 3 \equiv_{10}$

$1 + 16^3 + 81^3*3 \equiv $

$1 +6^3 + 1^3*3\equiv $

$1 + 36*6 + 3 \equiv $

$1 + 6*6 + 3\equiv $

$1 + 36 + 3\equiv $

$1 + 6 + 3\equiv 10 \equiv 0$.

So $11^{11} + 12^{12} + 13^{13}$ has remainder $0$ when divided by $10$ which is to say $11^11 + 12^{12} +13^{13}$ is divisible by $10$.

====

A number is devisible by $10$ if and only if the last digit is $0$.

And value of the last digits arithmetically "distribute".  That is if the last digit of $n$ is $a$ then the last digit of $n^k$ is the last digit of $a^k$.  (Because $n = 10b +a$ so $n^k =(10b + a)^k = abunchofmultiplesof(10) + a^k$) and if the last digit of $n$ is $a$ and the last digit of $m$ is $c$ then the last digit of $m + n$ is the last digit of $b+1$ and the last digit of $m\times n$ is the last digit of $b\times c$.

So $11^{11}+12^{12}+13^{13}$ is divisible by $10$ if only if its last digit is $0$.

And the last digit of $11^{11}+12^{12}+13^{13}$ is the last digit of $1^{11}+2^{12}+3^{13}$

$1^{11} = 1$.

$2^{12} = 2^4\times 2^4 \times 2^4 = 16\times 16\times 16$ so the last digit is the same as $6\times 6\times 6$ so the last digit is the same as $6\times 6=36$ so the last digit is $6$.

$3^{13} = 3^4\times 3^4 \times 3^4 \times 3$.  $3^4 = 81$ so the last digit of $3^{13}$ is the last digit of $1\times1\times 1\times 3 = 3$>

So the last digit of $11^{11}+12^{12}+13^{13}$ is the same as the last digit of $1 + 6 + 3 =10$.  And that digit is $0$.

So, yes, $11^{11}+12^{12}+13^{13}$ *is* divisible by $10$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$11\equiv1\;\mathtt{mod}(10) \Rightarrow {11^{11}}\equiv {1^{11}}\equiv1 \;\mathtt{mod}(10)$$
Analugously $${12^{12}}\equiv{2^{12}}\equiv{(2^6)^2}\equiv{64^2}\equiv6\;\mathtt{mod}(10)$$
$${13^{13}}\equiv{(13^4)^2}*13\equiv{1^2}*3\equiv3\; \mathtt{mod}(10)$$
Thus
$${11^{11}}+{12^{12}}+{13^{13}}\equiv1+6+3\equiv 0\; \mathtt{mod}(10)$$
$$\therefore10\mid \bigl({11^{11}}+{12^{12}}+{13^{13}}\bigr)$$

You can alternatively use the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem):
$$11^{11}=(10+1)^{11}=\sum_{k=0}^{11}\binom{11}{k}10^k=\binom{11}{0}10^0+\binom{11}{1}10^1+\binom{11}{2}10^2+\ldots+\binom{11}{11}10^{11}$$
$$=1+11*10+55*100+\ldots+10^{11}=1+10\Bigl(11+550+\ldots+10^{10}\Bigr)$$

$$12^{12}=(10+2)^{12}=\sum_{k=0}^{12}\binom{12}{k}10^k2^{12-k}=\binom{12}{0}10^02^{12}+\binom{12}{1}10^12^{11}+\binom{12}{2}10^22^{10}+\ldots+\binom{12}{12}10^{12}=2^{12}+12*10*2^{11}+66*100*2^{10}+\ldots+10^{12}$$ $$=2^{12}+10\Bigl(12*2^{11}+660*2^{10}+\ldots+10^{11}\Bigr)$$

$$13^{13}=(10+3)^{13}=\sum_{k=0}^{13}\binom{13}{k}10^k3^{13-k}=\binom{13}{0}10^03^{13}+\binom{13}{1}10^13^{12}+\binom{13}{2}10^23^{11}+\ldots+\binom{13}{13}10^{13}=3^{13}+13*10*3^{12}+78*100*3^{11}+\ldots+10^{13}$$ $$=3^{13}+10\Bigl(13*3^{12}+780*3^{11}+\ldots+10^{12}\Bigr)$$

Thus $${11^{11}}+{12^{12}}+{13^{13}}$$ $$=1+10\Bigl(11+550+\ldots+10^{10}\Bigr)+2^{12}+10\Bigl(12*2^{11}+660*2^{10}+\ldots+10^{11}\Bigr)+3^{13}+10\Bigl(13*3^{12}+780*3^{11}+\ldots+10^{12}\Bigr)$$ $$=1+2^{12}+3^{13}+10\Biggl(\cdots\Biggr)$$

Now $$1+2^{12}+3^{13}=1+2^{3*4}+3^{3*4}*3=1+8^4+9^4*3=1+64^2+81^2*3$$ $$=1+4096+6561*3=23780\Rightarrow 10\mid (1+2^{12}+3^{13})$$

And we would be done.

PS:

I still find the modular approach easier and more elegant...

Answer (score 0):

Simple calculation :

$11 \equiv 1 (mod 10)$ $\implies$ $11^{11} \equiv 1 (mod 10)$

$12 \equiv 2 (mod 10)$ $\implies$ $12^{12} \equiv 6 (mod 10)$

$13 \equiv 3 (mod 10)$ $\implies$ $13^{13} \equiv 3 (mod 10)$

Hence
$11^{11} + 12^{12} + 13^{13} \equiv 1+6+3 \equiv 0 (mod 10)$

Answer (score 0):

The final digit of $11^{11}$ is easy. If we are able to use Fermat-Euler we have that $\varphi (10)=4$ so that if $n$ is coprime to $10$ then $n^4\equiv 1$ and that applies with $n=3$ so that $13^{13}\equiv 3^{12}\cdot 3\equiv 3 \bmod 10$.

$12$ is more interesting - we can't use the coprime property. The exponent is small enough that you can do it by hand, but here is another trick (working modulo $10$).

First $12^{12}\equiv 2^{12}$

Then $12^{12}=3^{12}\cdot 4^{12}\equiv \left(2^{12}\right)^2$ (we did $3^{12}\equiv 1$ already)

Let $2^{12}\equiv m$, then $m^2\equiv m$ from the two calculations above, and $m$ is even and non-zero, so must be $6$.

---

I added this because it is interesting, and very occasionally such alternative ways of working save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily prove it without any modular arithmetic. Just look at the last digits.

$$3^1 = \color{blue}{3} \quad 3^2 = \color{blue}{9} \quad 3^3 = 2\color{blue}{7} \quad 3^4 = 8\color{blue}{1} \implies 3, 9, 7, 1, 3, 9, 7, 1, ...$$

$$2^1 = \color{green}{2} \quad 2^2 = \color{green}{4} \quad 2^3 = \color{green}{8} \quad 2^4 = 1\color{green}{6} \implies 2, 4, 8, 6, 2, 4, 8, 6, ...$$

The pattern loops every $4^{th}$ exponent, as you can see. Notice that $13^{13}$ must end with whatever $3^{13}$ ends with, and $2^{12}$ must end with whatever $2^{12}$ ends with.

$$13 = \color{purple}{3}(4)+\color{blue}{1} \quad\text{Three loops done; first exponent}$$

$$12 = \color{purple}{2}(4)+\color{green}{4} \quad\text{Two loops done; fourth exponent}$$

Thus, $13^{13}$ ends with $\color{blue}{3}$ and $12^{12}$ ends with $\color{green}{6}$. $11^{11}$ obviously ends with $1$, so what does the unit digit become?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know modular arithmetic we can instead employ the Binomial Theorem.

**Theorem** $\ 10\ $ divides $\ (1\!+\!10a)^{\large k}\!+ (2\!+\!10b)^{\large  4n}\!+(3\!+\!10c)^{\large 1+4n}\ $ for $\,a,b,c\in\Bbb Z,\ k,n\in \Bbb N$

**Proof** $\ $ To show it's divisible by $10$ it suffices to show it's divisible by $\,2\,$ and $\,5\,$. Notice it has parity odd + even + odd = even, so $\,2\,$ divides it. Below we show that $\,5\,$ divides it too.

Note that $\ \ (x\,+\,\color{#c00}5y)^{\large m}\, =\,\ x^{\large m}\, +\, \color{#c00}5(\cdots)\ \ \ \,$ by $\ \rm\color{#0a0}{BT}$ := Binomial Theorem, for $(\cdots)$  an integer.

$\!\!\begin{align} {\rm Therefore}\, \ 
(2+10b)^{\large 4n} &=\  2^{\large 4n}\,+\, 5\,i,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \, \text{for an integer } i, \ \text{by } \rm\color{#0a0}{BT}\ as\ above\\[.2em]
&= (1\!+\!15)^{\large n}\! + 5\,i\\[,2em]
&=\  \color{darkorange}1 + 5\,j\, +\, 5\,i, \ \ \ \text{for an integer } j, \ \text{by } \rm\color{#0a0}{BT}\ as\ above\\
\end{align}$

Similarly $\,\ (1+10a)^{\large k}\ \ =\,\ \color{#0a0}1 + 5\,d$

and also $\ \ (3+10c)^{\large 1+4n}\! = \color{#90f}3 + 5\,e$

Therefore their sum equals $\: \color{darkorange}1 + \color{#0a0}1 + \color{#90f}3 + 5(\cdots) = $ multiple of $5.\ \ $ **QED**

Comment: Alternatively we can replace the **Binomial Theorem** by the **Factor Theorem** as follows

$$\large z^m\!-x^m = (z\!-\!x)(\cdots)\ \ {\rm for}\ \ z=x\!+\!5y\,\ {\rm has\ factor}\ \  z-x = \color{#c00}5y\ \ {\rm so\ is\ divisible\ by}\,\ \color{#c00}5\quad$$

This method is used in Barry's answer. $\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

The first digit of $11^{11}=$ the first digit of $1^{11}=$ $1$.

---

The first digit of $12^5$ equals the first digit of $2^5=$ the first digit of $32=2$.

$\text{(The first digit of $12^{10}) =$ (The first digit of $12^5)^2 = 4$ }$.

$\text{(The first digit of $12^{12}) =
       $ (The first digit of $12^{10}) \times($The first digit of $12^2)  = 6$ }$.

---

$\text{(The first digit of $13^{4}) =$ (The first digit of $3^4) = 1$ }$.

$\text{(The first digit of $13^{12}) =$ (The first digit of $(13^4)^3) = 1$ }$.

$\text{(The first digit of $13^{13}) =$ (The first digit of $13^{12} \times 3) = 3$ }$.

---

$\text{(The first digit of $11^{11} + 12^{12} + 13^{13}) =$
       (The first digit of $1+6+3) = 0$ }$.

---

Hence $11^{11} + 12^{12} + 13^{13}$ is a multiple of $10$

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that

$\tag 1 10 \displaystyle \text{ divides } a + 10 \cdot b \; \text{ if and only if }\; 10 \text{ divides } a $

We'll now construct a list of numeric expressions separated by $//$; either all the expressions are divisible by $10$ or none of them are. The OP should be able to follow the logic, which uses $\text{(1)}$ over and over, sometimes using it more than once in one step.

$\displaystyle 11^{11}+12^{12}+13^{13} \quad // $
$\displaystyle (10+1)\cdot 11^{10}+(10+2)\cdot12^{11}+(10+3)\cdot13^{12} \quad // $
$\displaystyle 1^{10} \cdot 11 +2^{11}\cdot 12+3^{12} \cdot 13 \quad // $
$\displaystyle 1 +2^{12}+3^{13}  \quad // $
$\displaystyle 1+4^{6}+3\cdot3^{12} \quad // $
$\displaystyle 1+16^{3}+3\cdot9^{6} \quad // $
$\displaystyle 1+6^{3}+3\cdot81^{3} \quad // $
$\displaystyle 1+6\cdot36+3\cdot 1^{3} \quad // $
$\displaystyle 1+6\cdot6+3 \quad // $
$\displaystyle 40$

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have knowledge of modular arithmetic.

$11\equiv 1\mod 10\implies 11^{11}\equiv 1\mod 10$.

$12\equiv 2\mod 10\implies 12^6\equiv 2^6 \mod10\equiv 4\mod 10$ $\implies 12^{12}\equiv 4^2\mod 10\equiv 6\mod 10$.

$13\equiv 3 \mod 10\implies 13^4\equiv 3^4 \mod 10\equiv 1 \mod 10\implies 13^{13}\equiv 3\mod 10.$

So $11^{11}+12^{12}+13^{13}\equiv 1+6+3 \mod 10\equiv 0 \mod 10.$

Hence $11^{11}+12^{12}+13^{13}$ is divisible by 10.

Comment: "Assuming you have knowledge of modular arithmetic."  I think that's a big assumption.  But $\mod 10$ can be explained in one sentence  to an extent that the OP can understand it

Comment: But it can get mathematical then. It would be based on logical arguments rather than mathematical deductions.

Comment: I absolutely agree!!!

Answer (score -1):

When calculating in (mod 10) we get $11^{11}+12^{12}+12^{13}=1^{11}+2^{12}+3^{13}=1+6+3=10$. Here I knew $2^{10} =1024$, so $2^{12}=6(mod10)$ and $3$ has order $4$ in $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ so $3^{13}=3^{12}*3=3$.