# How to show that $12^{12} + 9^{9}$ can be divided by $15$ using Binomial Theorem?

Tags: divisibility, binomial-theorem

How to show that $12^{12} + 9^{9}$ can be divided by $15$ using Binomial Theorem?

I don't know where to start, given the specific method needed.
Since both powers are divisible by 3, I know that the sum is divisible by 3.
I don't know how to show that the sum is also divisible by 5.

Comment: Do you know Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: Try expressing $12^9=(10+2)^9$ and $9^{12}=(10-1)^{12}$.  You'll see that @JoséCarlosSantos is correct.  When divided by $5$, the sum has a remainder of $3$.

Comment: The sum is *not* divisible by $5$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog, good day. Familiar but I will try to learn how to use it.

Comment: @RobertShore Thanks for the comment. I just have to expand it and show that every addend is divisible by 5. Am I right? or there is a better way?

Comment: All but one of the addends will be divisible by $5$.

Comment: On the other hand, $12^{12}+9^9$ *is* divisible by $5$ and by $15$

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, ladies, and gentlemen. I am sorry for the error on the exponenents.

Comment: **Hint** $\, $ Write it as: $\ (\color{#c00}{145}-1)^{\large 6} + (\color{#c00}{10}-1)^{\large 9}$ and note $5$ divides $\color{#c00}{145,\, 10}.\,$ Similarly, more generally we can show that  $a$ divides $(ab-1)^{2n}+(ac-1)^{2k+1}\ \ $

Comment: Use the above hint along with the Binomial Theorem as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3013406/242) or as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3838498/242) in the linked dupes. It is better to learn modular arithmetic for problems like this, as mentioned in remarks there.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly it's divisible by 3, it suffices to prove it's divisible by 5. Consider

$$12^{12}+9^9\equiv(10+2)^{12}+(10-1)^9\equiv 2^{12}+(-1)^9=4095\equiv0, \mod 5$$

Comment: note that $2^4\equiv1\pmod5$, so $2^{12}\equiv1\pmod5$

Comment: Yep there are too many ways. I used $2^{12}=4096$ too frequently :D

Comment: Easier: $\,12^{12} = (145-1)^6\overset{\rm BT} \equiv (-1)^6\equiv 1\pmod{\! 5}.\,$ It's easier to use mod arithmetic (e.g. [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)) rather than BT = Binomial Theorem.